# Make an SQL request more efficient and tidy?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT Phrases.*
FROM Phrases
WHERE (((Phrases.phrase) Like "*ing aids*") 
  AND ((Phrases.phrase) Not Like "*getting*") 
  AND ((Phrases.phrase) Not Like "*contracting*")) 
  AND ((Phrases.phrase) Not Like "*preventing*"); //(etc.)
```

Now, if I were using RegEx, I might bunch all the Nots into one big (getting|contracting|preventing), but I'm not sure how to do this in SQL.

Is there a way to render this query more legibly/elegantly?

Comment: Which flavour of RDBMS?  Because some of them support RegEx (e.g. Oracle 10g+).  Although even with RegEx that would be pretty convoluted.

Comment: I doubt that by incorporating regular expressions you could make it more efficient. Apart from that, not every DBMS supports them, so which do you use?

Comment: It's a local .mdb file, and I'm writing the queries in MS Access 2007. 

As I explain in my comment below, I'm just looking for a bit of information (an unknown subset of the data, in this case "hearing aids", "reading aids", etc.), and I'm trying to refine a query that's handwritten for that particular moment.

Of course, each of the next queries will be slightly different, but probably I'll need a way to do this there as well.

Comment: aaaaand I see that Access doesn't support regular expressions. OCH.
HOWEVER, I did learn how to do it in SQL. Yay!

Comment: If you're interested in using RegEx in Access, it's available via the File System Object. But it won't use indexes, as it's not in the Jet/ACE database engine, but in VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just by removing redundant stuff and using a consistent naming convention your SQL looks way cooler:

```
SELECT *
FROM phrases
WHERE phrase     LIKE '%ing aids%'
  AND phrase NOT LIKE '%getting%'
  AND phrase NOT LIKE '%contracting%' 
  AND phrase NOT LIKE '%preventing%'
```

You talk about regular expressions. Some DBMS do have it: MySQL, Oracle... However, the choice of either syntax should take into account the execution plan of the query: "how quick it is" rather than "how nice it looks".

Comment: I'm not so much looking for performance -- I'm running handwritten queries on a fixed dataset, to try to remove irrelevant data -- as I am looking for a simple way to add more and more refinements till I find the information I need.
As such, in the example above, I keep adding another gerund that I want to keep out of the results, and thought perhaps there's a more efficient way than adding a whole line.

Comment: Well, it's not pretty like a regex, but it works in Access. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, you're able to use [regular expression where-clause parameters](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/):

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE column REGEXP 'regexp'
```

So if that's what you're using, you could write a regular expression string that is possibly a bit more compact that your 4 `like` criteria.  It may not be as easy to see what the query is doing for other people, however.

It looks like SQL Server [offers a similar feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Sinec it sounds like you're building this as you go to mine your data, here's something that you could consider:

```
CREATE TABLE Includes (phrase VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE Excludes (phrase VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO Includes VALUES ('%ing aids%')
INSERT INTO Excludes VALUES ('%getting%')
INSERT INTO Excludes VALUES ('%contracting%')
INSERT INTO Excludes VALUES ('%preventing%')

SELECT
     *
FROM
     Phrases P
WHERE
     EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Includes I WHERE P.phrase LIKE I.phrase) AND
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Excludes E WHERE P.phrase LIKE E.phrase)
```

You are then always just running the same query and you can simply change what's in the Includes and Excludes tables to refine your searches.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I'm guessing there's no simpler solution with an array variable in SQL, though, is there.

Comment: Hmm.
I'm really beginning to like this.

Comment: Okay, trying to implement this, I've found a problem -- I can't do any ORs there. So I can't combine things. For example, finding 'art' and ('school' or 'degree') but not 'part'.

Comment: You could add a bit column to the Includes table for required or optional terms. Then just get a count of how many of those rows are matched for each type. The required count would have to match the count of required terms for the search and the overall count would have to be at least one. If I have time later I'll try to put together a query, but maybe this can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what SQL server you are using, it may support REGEX itself.  For example, google searches show that SQL Server, Oracle, and mysql all support regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could push all your negative criteria into a short circuiting CASE expression (works Sql Server, not sure about MSAccess).

```
SELECT *
FROM phrases
WHERE phrase LIKE '%ing aids%'
  AND CASE
    WHEN phrase LIKE '%getting%' THEN 2
    WHEN phrase LIKE '%contracting%' THEN 2
    WHEN phrase LIKE '%preventing%' THEN 2
    ELSE 1
  END = 1
```

On the "more efficient" side, you need to find some criteria that allows you to avoid reading the entire Phrases column.  Double sided wildcard criteria is bad.  Right sided wildcard criteria is good.

Comment: Jet/ACE/Access does not support CASE, so this answer is useless and should be deleted.